# Disable listener being blocked on redelivery - ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

ActiveMQ 5.2 to 5.6 (not sure if all JMS) blocks the listener when there is a re-delivery of the message. Is there a way that we can suspend the blocking of the listener and allow it to process other messages during this retries period (say retry is after 2 seconds)?

Is there any updates to 5.7 and above which disables this blocking listeners?

Answer (score 2):

Actually there should be an option for you to enable in 5.6 clients to perform non-blocking redelivery.  This feature was added for this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-1853).  This is not a feature you want to use without understanding though as it alters delivery order.  There were also a few fixes and improvements for this feature between 5.6 and 5.7, you can view the issue in the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) for each release.

To enable this feature you would add the flag to the client URI:

```
jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=true
```